# Nutch 2.1 cannot setup in Mac

Tags: nutch

Trying to set up the new Nutch 2.1 in local environments. With the fresh download, then "ant build". Following the document from wiki http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/Nutch2Tutorial however, it seems that no luck

I got the following errors:

```
java[1815:1903] Unable to load realm info from SCDynamicStore
InjectorJob: org.apache.gora.util.GoraException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException
    at org.apache.gora.store.DataStoreFactory.createDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:167)
    at org.apache.gora.store.DataStoreFactory.createDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:135)
    at org.apache.nutch.storage.StorageUtils.createWebStore(StorageUtils.java:75)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.run(InjectorJob.java:214)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.inject(InjectorJob.java:228)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.run(InjectorJob.java:248)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.main(InjectorJob.java:258)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getMaster(HConnectionManager.java:394)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.(HBaseAdmin.java:94)
    at org.apache.gora.hbase.store.HBaseStore.initialize(HBaseStore.java:108)
    at org.apache.gora.store.DataStoreFactory.initializeDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:102)
    at org.apache.gora.store.DataStoreFactory.createDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:161)
    ... 7 more
```

Your help is highly appreciated. thanks

Comment: I have the same problem. I installed HBase 0.94.3 , ZooKeeper 3.4.5 , Nutch 2.1 . After HBase & ZooKeeper successfully started, I run `bin/nutch inject result/urls.txt`. (the `urls.txt` contains URLs to inject.) same exception encountered. I'm using Mac OS X 10.7.5

Comment: I found the resolution for this question after checked the logs carefully. Check your regionservers under hbase/conf and /etc/hosts to see if they are matched.

Answer (score 2):

```
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException
```

this indicates that the clsuter setup is not done correctly. The nutch tutorial page mentions this:

> Install and configure HBase. You can get it here (N.B. Gora 0.2 uses
>   HBase 0.90.4, however the setup is known to work with more recent
>   versions of the HBase 0.90.x branch)

Have you performed this step correctly ?

Comment: HBase is the tricky part, I tried Hbase 0.90.5 (Cannot locate 0.90.4 in stable list). and I am able to use the shell to test it. Now I am trying to use virtualbox with ubuntu. Is it possible some conflicts running such environment in Mac?

Comment: Honestly i have never tried running things on Mac but having a ubuntu with virtualbox would be ok. Regarding this issue, i think that u should check the HBase installation by running some decent operation on it and also verify if the nutch-hbase linking is done correctly.